# How to replace the cache driver?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel application and i want to improve the site's performance by using Redis as a cache driver. i want to make sure that the page will load faster the next time (if the user is moved to google or whatever and come back or if the user moved to other page in my site and come back to lets say the home page).

I want to know how i can activate it in my application, because i added Redis but i do not see anything faster.

i did this in Redis config file:

`sudo apt install redis-server`

`sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`

changed supervised no to supervised systemd.

and make sure it run ok by running redis-cli and running inside the prompt: ping which gave me PONG response.

then, in my .env file i changed this: CACHE_DRIVER=file to this: CACHE_DRIVER=redis.
and restarted nginx to make sure it got the changes. and no errors at all.

Comment: Do you have code that is using `Cache::xxxxx`? It could also be the database, but you are asking how to _profile_ your site. You could use Clockwork or Laravel Debugbar, but I have never used them in production, so you have to be careful who can see it...

Comment: nginx just functions as a proxy passing requests forward to PHP, and for PHP to pick up changes to the `.env` file, you may have to at least restart the PHP-FPM service. maybe there is a local file-based cache you'll have to delete/rebuild, by running CLI commands or moving folders, as well, to see any changes.

Comment: Imagine you are having the possibility to purge the caching, purge the cache, make the first call that fills the cache make a subsequent call with most likely quicker response time. Does not have to be that complex, and if you can't notice the performance immediately on the request timer in postman or similar, you are caching wrong :)

Comment: @mch thank you! i see now that the website is much more fast. i just did a restart to the php-fpm service.

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited the question a little bit to be better understood by others.

Answer (score -1):

Rashenter fixed the problem by reloading the PHP-FPM service instead of nginx. PHP is less deeply integrated into nginx than into Apache, and reloding the nginx service won't change much in most cases.

Some applications have more nested caching structures and the output of .env files can be stored in other locations (for example inside another php-file cache). In that case simply restarting PHP won't help, but those files will have to be deleted / rebuilt as well.